# Zoho Deluge : How can I insert line breaks or start a new line to e-mail message?

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I am trying to send an email by using Zoho Custom Function. Now, I need to insert line breaks in my email. I try by using `\n` but it does not work.

```
sendmail
    [
        from: "email@gmail.com"
        to: "email@gmail.com"
        subject: Subject
        message: "Hello, \nThe Name has been updated to the stage. Below is a link to the record for more details:\n link \nRegards, \nBRKTHRU"
    ]
```

Comment: https://help.zoho.com/portal/kb/articles/how-can-i-insert-line-breaks-to-my-e-mail-message - have you tried both of these?

Comment: Thank's @ColonD for your recommendation.
:)

Answer (score 3):

Got the solution

A message could be sent as "Plain Text" or "HTML".  Use 
 tag if the content is HTML and \n if the content type is "plain text".  For example

```
sendmail
[
    To       :  zoho.loginuserid 
    From     :  zoho.adminuserid 
    Subject  :  "To insert line breaks" 
    Message  :  "Dear Customer, "+ "<br>Your order has been processed"
]
```

Got answer from [Zoho help link](https://help.zoho.com/portal/kb/articles/how-can-i-insert-line-breaks-to-my-e-mail-message)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use HTML. Try inserting some `<br><br>` instead of \n

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for resurrecting an old post, but you can also contact Zoho support and ask them to enable "\n" for your system. Should be enabled by default so we don't have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This Works for me :)

```
sendmail
[
    from: "email@gmail.com"
    to: "email@gmail.com"
    subject: Subject
    message: "Hello "+<br>+"World"
]
```